# tree menu in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a tree menu (similar to the javascript tree menu) in my rails application. I have been looking at acts_as_tree and was wondering if there exists any other way of doing it.

Is there a better way of creating tree menu rather than using 'acts_as_tree' or should i stick with the javascript tree menu?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) gem or [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem

Comment: Thanks, am going to have a look at this :)